# How to send image as Message (SMS) in ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I want to send image as a message (SMS) + text from iPad or iPhone then What should I implement in my application? I want to let you know that I am working on ios5.

Answer (score 1):

You can prompt the user to send a text message by presenting a [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Currently, it only allows you to set the body text. (No support for images)